# Platform event Fired from two objects

Tags: apex, limits, bestpractice, platform-event, publish-subscribe

We are planning to build a platform event, which should publish changes from two objects.

Consider there is an insert/update of records in Account object or Customer__c object.

We need to insert/update some information from the above action into a 3rd object AccountCustomer__c using platform event.

AccountCustomer__c will be the subscriber whenever data is changed in  Account or Customer__c object.

Is it possible to use a single platform event to push changes from more than one object?

Are there any limitations to be considered?

Any help or examples of such scenario would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Platform Events can be absolutely used in this case.

Just to recall, Platform Event is similar to a Custom Object, has its own set of fields and is not tied to any other Object hence it can be used to transact changes from different source objects, as long as both source objects provides values for same fields.

Now write logic in each of the Object's (trigger or flow), construct PlatformEvent record and publish which can be received by Platform Event trigger and saved into `AccountCustomer__c` object.